# WinForms returns different scale factor values for Width and Height

Tags: c#, winforms, autoscalemode

I have a .NET WinForms dialog and I am using the **AutoScaleFactor** property of the Form in Form_Resize event to get the scale factor. If I set the scaling to 200% (for my 1920x1080 resolution), the scale factor should be **Width=2,Height=2** but it comes as **Width=2,Height=1.923077** and this causes a minor difference in the pixel calculation.

Why is it returning two different values? Isn't it suppose to return the same value for both Width and Height?

I have an embedded IE Browser control and I calculate the scale values through JavaScript using the following code:

```js
var scaleFactorX = screen.deviceXDPI / screen.logicalXDPI;
var scaleFactorY = screen.deviceYDPI / screen.logicalYDPI;
alert('ScaleFactor X=' + scaleFactorX + ', Y=' + scaleFactorY);
```

then it displays **Width=2,Height=2**

Comment: The default AutoScaleMode is Font, it tries to deal with fonts taking proportionally more space horizontally at small point sizes.  You prefer Dpi, but be sure to keep enough elbow room.

Comment: Yes, just figured that out that the AutoScaleMode is set to Font. Setting it to DPI gives the same values for both. Thanks.

Comment: @HansPassant Please post your comment as an answer so this issue becomes resolved.

Comment: Surely you got enough of a hint to complete the Q+A by yourself?  I'm sure everybody is interested in how that turned out, font scaling can be tricky.

Comment: I can fix the issue by setting AutoScaleMode=Dpi but if I want to keep the default "Font" scale mode then I am not sure if there is a way to set the same option for the browser control on that Form. I've made the WebBrowser Dpi Aware through the DOCHOSTUIFLAG.DPI_AWARE mechanism and I think that defaults to the DPI scale mode because in JS I always get the same values for horizontal and vertical.